# Cudatoolkit with python interpreter. Conda errors

Tags: scripting, gpu

I'm working on a plugin for blender and I wanted to add some external libraries to blender. I found my blender python.exe, and I added a few libraries like this:

```
.\python.exe -m pip install pacakge_name
```

It works fine, but you as far as I know you need conda to install cudatoolkit(so I installed conda), but when I try to use:

```
.\python.exe -m conda install cudatoolikt
```

It raises an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytoolz' Installing cytoolz raises an error that no file python.h is found.

Is there any other option to install cudatoolkit? Do you have any ideas how to fix these errors, and why my conda is not working correctly?